# How can we implement scalable Compute Grid with massive concurrent memory updates supporting low latency and consistency

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop, mapreduce, ignite

We are implementing low-latency distributed computation system with the cluster of Apache Ignite. All data is stored in memory. Now we support about 600 requests for distributed computations per second with latency about 50-200 ms. Computations are really complex and involve different caches. And we also support updates of our data.

We faced a problem of scalability when data is updated while reading at the same time. Our data is not atomic (multiple caches involve). Actually all data is divided into segments, and we distribute such segments through cluster.
While making search computation each node scans all its local segments and finds result.

When we make a single update we affect a single segment, where that data is stored.

But the problem is, the whole search computation is blocked or repeating during a single segment update on a single node to support consistency on a whole result.

I know that Hadoop restrict such cases and does not allow to update in HDFS, only save new version. But that is not our case, because collecting different versions of data requires a lot of memory and causes duplicates.

Is there any architectural techniques to support scalability with such updates?

We have tried to implement OPTIMISTIC trasactions with repeats, but computations repeat very often. READ_COMMITED level broke consistency. REPEATABLE_READ is blocking.

Comment: I'm afraid it will be hard to suggest anything meaningful without diving into the details of the use case and without understanding why the whole computation has to be blocked (from a business standpoint) if just one of the segments on one node gets updated. 

However, I'm not concerned about the latency and throughput requirements, those are achievable - was involved in the projects that use Ignite for credit cards authorization and payments with 20-50 SLAs for 99.99 percentile. Email me at dmagda at gridgain dot com.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can take a block of transactions (a segment?), optimize it by removing duplicates and joining operations working on same keys to make a single operation, then running the remainder transactionally.